# Setting X-Azure-FDID header using an ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-front-door

I am trying to automate setting up my App Service behind an Azure Front Door using ARM templates. I've been able to set the ipSecurityRestrictions object to restrict it to any Front Door [(see this stack overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461510/how-to-configure-web-apps-such-that-they-cannot-be-accessed-directly/62520836#62520836)- but I also want to set the X-Azure-FDID header so I can restrict to only my Azure Front Door.

I've set my siteConfig with the below ipSecurityRestrictions object but the X-Azure-FDID header is not being set. I've tried to set the header as property as well as a list.

```
"ipSecurityRestrictions": [
              {
                "ipAddress": "AzureFrontDoor.Backend",
                "action": "Allow",
                "tag": "ServiceTag",
                "priority": 100,
                "name": "Front Door Access Only",
                "description": "Rule to allow front door access",
                "headers": {
                  "x-azure-fdid": [
                    "[parameters('frontDoorID')]"
                  ]
                }
              },
                {
                    "ipAddress": "Any",
                    "action": "Deny",
                    "priority": 2147483647,
                    "name": "Deny all",
                    "description": "Deny all access"
                }
            ],
```

When I run my arm template, I don't see any errors. When I go to the deployed resources to export the deployed template, the headers setting is not in the deployed resource. I am [reviewing the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/config-web?tabs=json#IpSecurityRestriction) and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
"ipSecurityRestrictions": [
                           {
                               "ipAddress": "AzureFrontDoor.Backend",
                               "action": "Allow",
                               "tag": "ServiceTag",
                               "priority": 100,
                               "name": "Front Door Access Only",
                               "description": "Rule to allow front door access"
                           },
                           {
                               "ipAddress": "Any",
                               "action": "Deny",
                               "priority": 2147483647,
                               "name": "Deny all",
                               "description": "Deny all access"
                           }
                       ],
```

I found one [other stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67668065/include-front-door-id-in-arm-template-iprestriction#) question that's my same issue- however this did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is correct- Azure Portal was delayed in updating